# Why when creating histogram channels by colors it keep saving the same channel blue color?

Tags: c#, winforms

a bit long but it's all connected.

I'm assigning in this method to the channelValue according to the channelColor:

```
private int[] CalculateChannelHistogram(Bitmap image, Color channelColor)
        {
            int[] histogram = new int[256];

            BitmapData imageData = image.LockBits(
                new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height),
                ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            unsafe
            {
                byte* ptr = (byte*)imageData.Scan0;

                for (int y = 0; y < imageData.Height; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < imageData.Width; x++)
                    {
                        byte channelValue = 0;

                        if (channelColor == Color.Red)
                            channelValue = ptr[y * imageData.Stride + x * 4 + 2];
                        else if (channelColor == Color.Green)
                            channelValue = ptr[y * imageData.Stride + x * 4 + 1];
                        else if (channelColor == Color.Blue)
                            channelValue = ptr[y * imageData.Stride + x * 4];

                        histogram[channelValue]++;
                    }
                }
            }

            image.UnlockBits(imageData);

            return histogram;
        }
```

then using it in this button click event:

```
private async void btnOpenVideo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Initialize the CancellationTokenSource
            cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            // Initialize the histograms list
            histograms = new List<int[]>();

            using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                openFileDialog.Filter = "Video Files (*.mp4;*.avi;*.mkv)|*.mp4;*.avi;*.mkv|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyVideos);

                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string videoPath = openFileDialog.FileName;

                    // Open the video file using VideoFileReader
                    using (VideoFileReader videoReader = new VideoFileReader())
                    {
                        videoReader.Open(videoPath);

                        // Get the total number of frames in the video
                        int totalFrames = (int)videoReader.FrameCount;

                        // Clear any existing curves on the graph
                        zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear();

                        // Set the maximum value of the progress bar
                        progressBar1.Value = 0;
                        progressBar1.Maximum = totalFrames;

                        // Disable the button to prevent multiple extractions
                        btnOpenVideo.Enabled = false;

                        histograms.Clear();

                        // Process each frame in the video
                        await Task.Run(async () =>
                        {
                            for (int frameIndex = 0; frameIndex < totalFrames; frameIndex++)
                            {
                                // Check if cancellation is requested
                                if (cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                                    break;

                                // Read the video frame
                                Bitmap frame = videoReader.ReadVideoFrame(frameIndex);

                                // Calculate and display histograms
                                int[] grayscaleHistogram = CalculateGrayscaleHistogram(frame);
                                int[] redHistogram = CalculateChannelHistogram(frame, Color.Red);
                                int[] greenHistogram = CalculateChannelHistogram(frame, Color.Green);
                                int[] blueHistogram = CalculateChannelHistogram(frame, Color.Blue);

                                histograms.Add(grayscaleHistogram);

                                // Plot histograms
                                PlotHistogram(grayscaleHistogram, "Grayscale Histogram", "Pixel Value", "Frequency", zedGraphControl1.GraphPane, Color.Blue);
                                PlotHistogram(redHistogram, "Red Channel Histogram", "Pixel Value", "Frequency", zedGraphControl1.GraphPane, Color.Red);
                                PlotHistogram(greenHistogram, "Green Channel Histogram", "Pixel Value", "Frequency", zedGraphControl1.GraphPane, Color.Green);
                                PlotHistogram(blueHistogram, "Blue Channel Histogram", "Pixel Value", "Frequency", zedGraphControl1.GraphPane, Color.Blue);

                                // Draw histogram information on the frame
                                DrawHistogramInformation(frame, grayscaleHistogram, "Grayscale Histogram");

                                // Save frame with histogram
                                
                                string frameFolder = Path.Combine(outputFolder, $"Frame_{frameIndex}");
                                if(!Directory.Exists(frameFolder))
                                {
                                    Directory.CreateDirectory(frameFolder);
                                }
                                string frameImagePath = Path.Combine(frameFolder, $"Frame_{frameIndex}.png");

                                frame.Save(frameImagePath, ImageFormat.Png);

                                // Save histogram values to text file
                                SaveHistogramValues(frameFolder, frameIndex, blueHistogram, redHistogram, greenHistogram);

                                // Save screenshot of ZedGraph controls
                                SaveGraphScreenshots(frameFolder, redHistogram, greenHistogram, blueHistogram);

                                // Update the PictureBox with the frame
                                pictureBox1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                                {
                                    pictureBox1.Image = frame;
                                    pictureBox1.Refresh();
                                }));

                                // Update the progress bar
                                progressBar1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                                {
                                    progressBar1.Value = frameIndex + 1;
                                }));

                                // Delay to slow down the processing (adjust as needed)
                                await Task.Delay(10);
                            }
                        });

                        // Refresh the graph after processing all frames
                        zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();
                        zedGraphControl1.Refresh();

                        // Show a message indicating the processing is complete
                        MessageBox.Show("Video processing completed.");

                        // Re-enable the button after extraction is complete
                        btnOpenVideo.Enabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

then last calling the SaveGraphScreenshots method:

in this SaveGraphScreenshots method I want to save a screenshot image to the hard drive of the channel color chart but only if the channel color have any data.  for example some frames can have data on channel red and green or only blue or only red but it keep saving all the channels it give it the names GreenHistogramGraph.png , HistogramGraph.png, RedHistogramGraph.png

where HistogramGraph.png is the blue channel.

and when I'm editing in paint the images they are all the same blue channel.

I want to save only the channels that have data inside. blue green red.  but it's saving only the same blue color channel just give different files names.

```
private void SaveGraphScreenshots(string frameFolderPath, int[] redHistogram, int[] greenHistogram, int[] blueHistogram)
        {
            if (redHistogram.Any() || greenHistogram.Any() || blueHistogram.Any())
            {
                if (blueHistogram.Any())
                {
                    string graphFilePath = Path.Combine(frameFolderPath, "HistogramGraph.png");
                    SaveGraphScreenshot(zedGraphControl1, graphFilePath);
                }

                if (redHistogram.Any())
                {
                    string redGraphFilePath = Path.Combine(frameFolderPath, "RedHistogramGraph.png");
                    SaveGraphScreenshot(zedGraphControl1, redGraphFilePath);
                }

                if (greenHistogram.Any())
                {
                    string greenGraphFilePath = Path.Combine(frameFolderPath, "GreenHistogramGraph.png");
                    SaveGraphScreenshot(zedGraphControl1, greenGraphFilePath);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if (redHistogram.Any())

`.Any()` checks if there is any item in the collection, and this will always be true, since the histogram will unconditionally contain 256 integers.

What you probably want to do is check if there is any value in the collection, except the zero index, that is larger than zero. I.e.

```
if (redHistogram.Skip(1).Any(v => v > 0))
```

Comment: is it even logic that one of the channels will be empty? I mean all the values will be zeros? or in image there will be always red green blue?

Comment: @shlomieshel good point, you would want to skip checking the zero-index.